# When to consider adopting multiple workspace orchestration approach

Tags: watson-assistant

I have a bot built in watson assistant with 150+ intents. Recently, clients complaint about performance of the bot, and dev team also found that intents conflicted with each other sometimes.

Then I searched for a solution online and read this [article](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/ibm-watson-conversation-multiple-workspace-orchestration-d51f003f5d11) which is about workspace orchestration. And this sounds like a feasible solution.

So my question is, when should we consider using this approach? like the number of intents or the avg confidence score of intent classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an orchestration layer doesn't solve the fundemental problem. At the end of the day if you split the intents per two assistants they will still be conflicting... often it will make them even more conflicting as you effectively made one instance of Watson Assistant blind to the other one.

There are many ways to improve your assistant, some of them are built-in to the product and some might require more work.

Here is a list of resources to get you going:

There is in Watson Assistant a built-in feature to detect conflicting intents and help resolving them.
Here is one of many? blogs about it https://cobusgreyling.medium.com/how-to-resolve-intent-conflicts-with-ibm-watson-assistant-1ee5ee09587e

There is quite a few resources provided by Watson Assistant to help you increase the quality of your assistant, but the following blog guides through the most recommended approaches:

https://medium.com/ibm-watson/the-quickest-way-to-improve-intents-in-a-chatbot-44bad1f3a5fc

Finally you should get acquainted with these python notebooks which help with analyzing and improving your assistant
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-improve-recommendations-notebook

Answer (score 1):

For solutions which may involve multiple subjects/topics, I mainly used and saw in use the **router** approach described in your link. For example, if your Chatbot can handle multiple subjects related to banking(Credit Cards, insurance, etc) each of those subjects can have a dedicated Watson Assistant skill. In front of those skills you should have the **router** one mentioned in your link which will be mainly used for identifying the user intent related to one of your subject's skills. In this skill you can publish as intents, all the example questions for that particular subject. In this way you can ensure that the **subject recognition** is always handled in this **router** skill. Also, in this skill you should consider maybe recognizing only intents which are hit with a high confidence(>0.8 for example). This will help you better recognize a subject, but you will need to ensure a proper training. The same intent confidence threshold mechanism can be applied for the intents which you need to recognize inside your subject skill.
This approach can help you better organize your skills and intents but it may become overwhelming in the case you only address one subject in your chatbot or if you have multiple subjects but with small number of intents.